# How to change the PyCharm interpreter in Raspbian os

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.6, raspbian, interpreter

I'm using raspbian os bullseye's latest version. In this version the default python is 3.9.2 but I want python 3.6.0. I changed the version in pi and added it to default but the pycharm interpreter only shows python 3.9.

How can I add python 3.6 interpreters in Pycharm in raspbian os?

Comment: you are running pycharm on the actual raspberry pi?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.